# What happens to the composition of a mixed gas plasma when de-ionizes back into a gas

Tags: plasma-physics, gas, states-of-matter, combustion

I've been thinking about this question for the past few days, but I'm not very well versed in plasma physics.

I am an aerospace engineering student in my senior year of college. A little while ago, I was thinking about jet engine ideas while I was doing my propulsion homework, and I came up with one that used plasma and magnetic fields to accelerate the intake air rather than combustion.

Basically it would breath either ambient air, like a regular turbojet engine, or pre-burned exhaust gas, like an afterburner. But once the gas is compressed, it would then pass through an ionization grid to be energized into a plasma, before accelerating through the rest of the engine with the help of magnetic fields.

I'm not sure if the engine would actually work or not, but I was curious about what would happen to the plasma after it got expelled out the back. Pretty much everything I've heard about plasmas before this used monoatomic gas in a controlled, empty environment; such as hydrogen or helium in a tokamak reactor.

If a mixed gas was used (such as air with different parts nitrogen, oxygen, carbon dioxide, etc.), what would happen to the composition of the gas when it is energized and ionized into a plasma?

After it leaves the engine, what kinds of gases and compounds would form in the resulting exhaust once the plasma begins to cool back down to the ambient temperature?

And would the byproducts of ionizing a mixed gas into a plasma be cleaner or dirtier than those of regular combustion; especially if it used pre-burned exhaust as the intake gas?

Comment: A plasma is electrically neutral, and recombination at atmospheric pressures is very fast.

Comment: In addition to Jon's point, if you ionized oxygen, you will cause lots of things to oxidize within such an engine.  This is generally a bad thing since rust usually doesn't enhance the materials useful properties.

Comment: @honeste_vivere But what if it used magnetic fields to contain the ionized gas from contacting the engine? I've seen the idea before for vacuum-optimized plasma engines, such as VASIMR. I just don't know how it would behave in atmosphere, or if the ionization chamber could somehow be kept at a near vacuum.

Comment: @JonCuster If plasma is electrically neutral, why is it so sensitive to magnetic fields? And if ionization won't work for heating gas into a plasma, what is a better way to heat it to a temperature where it could survive for at least 0.5 seconds to make it through the engine?

Comment: The plasma sheath is sensitive to magnetic fields because there is charge separation as the electrons try to outrun the more massive ions.